# Getting 0.0 when printing the return value of a method

Tags: java

```
class input{
    private double num1;
    private double num2;
    
    public void setNum1(double num1) {
        this.num1 = num1;
    }

    public double getNum1() {
        return this.num1;
    }
    
    public void setNum2(double num2) {
        this.num2 = num2;
    }

    public double getNum2() {
        return this.num2;
    }
}

class calculator extends input{
    double a = getNum1();
    double b = getNum2();
    
    double add() {
        return a+b;
    }
}

class advcalc extends calculator{
    double less() {
        return a-b;
    }
}

public class Inheritence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    advcalc cal = new advcalc();
    cal.setNum1(10);
    cal.setNum2(10);
    
    System.out.println(cal.add());
    }
}
```

Here I'm practicing inheritance. The first class gets inputs, second class is used for addition and 3rd is used for subtraction. I have created an object of 3rd class. After passing the inputs by `setNum1()` && `setNum1()`, when I try to print the return value of the add, it prints 0.0. I couldn't figure out what's the issue. Someone help me out please.

Comment: double a = getNum1(); -> this is executed before you execute your setters. get the values in the add method itself

Comment: You can put a `System.out.println(SOME VALUE)` in every method and constructor and check the flow of the code. This way You will get a clear idea.

Comment: @SayanBhattacharya thanks. Im sure it will help me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a = getNum()` is being executed before assigning the value.

```
double a = getNum1();
double b = getNum2();
double add() {
  return a+b;
}
```

instead of this you can assign the values inside `add` method.This way it will be assigned after you create an instance.

```
double a, b = 0;
double add() {
    this.a = getNum1();
    this.b = getNum2();
    return a + b;
}
```

There are various ways to achieve this . You can also pass the values in `add` method or create a `parameterized constructor`.

Answer (score 2):

In your code the variables `a` and `b`, defined in `calculator` will always be `0.0`, because they are set during the initialization of you object and only once:

1. You call `new advcalc()`
2. During initialization `double a = getNum1();` and `double b = getNum2();` are called
3. You call `setNum1` and change the value of `num1` in `input`, but a stays unchanged
4. You call `add` and `a` and `b` are both `0.0`

If you drop the variables `a` and `b` and call `getNum1` and `getNum2` in `add` it should work. You could also override `setNum1` and `setNum2` in `calculator` and set `a` and `b` there.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm practicing inheritance.

Then are you aware that `a` and `b` (in class `calculator`) are member variables<sup>1</sup> and that they are hiding<sup>2</sup> member variables `num1` and `num2` in the parent class (i.e. class `input`). Hiding can lead to problems (as you have discovered). Hence you should make `num1` and `num2` protected<sup>3</sup> and remove `a` and `b`.

Consider the following:
(Note that I changed the class names according to [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).)

```java
public class Inheritance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AdvCalc cal = new AdvCalc();
        cal.setNum1(10);
        cal.setNum2(10);
        System.out.println(cal.add());
    }
}

class Input {
    protected double num1;
    protected double num2;

    public void setNum1(double num1) {
        this.num1 = num1;
    }

    public double getNum1() {
        return this.num1;
    }

    public void setNum2(double num2) {
        this.num2 = num2;
    }

    public double getNum2() {
        return this.num2;
    }
}

class Calculator extends Input {
    public double add() {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}

class AdvCalc extends Calculator {
    public double less() {
        return num1 - num2;
    }
}
```

<sup>1</sup> Refer to [Declaring Member Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) (in Oracle's Java tutorials).
<sup>2</sup> Refer to [Variable Shadowing and Hiding in Java](https://dzone.com/articles/variable-shadowing-and-hiding-in-java)
<sup>3</sup> Refer to [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)